# search(), get(), and size() Java in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net

in java i'm using search(), get(), and size() this my codes in java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        String pre = "";
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            String command = scanner.next();
            if (command.equals("push")) {
                int value = scanner.nextInt();
                s.push(value);
            }
            else if (command.equals("pop")) {
                s.pop();
            }
            else if (command.equals("peeks")) {
                pre += (pre.equals("") ? "" : "\n") + s.peek();
            }
            else if (command.equals("search")) {
                int value = scanner.nextInt();
                pre += (pre.equals("") ? "" : "\n") + s.search(value);
            }
        }
        if (!pre.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(pre);
        }
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("kosong");
        }
        else {
            for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
                System.out.print(s.get(i) + (i==s.size()-1 ? "\n" : " "));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s.size());
        scanner.close();
    }
```

this my code in c# :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            String pre = "";
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                String command = Console.ReadLine();
                if (command.Equals("push")) {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    s.Push(value);
                }
                else if (command.Equals("pop")) {
                    s.Pop();
                }
                else if (command.Equals("peeks")) {
                    pre += (pre.Equals("") ? "" : "\n") + s.Peek();
                }
                else if (command.Equals("search")) {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    pre += (pre.Equals("") ? "" : "\n") + s.search(value);
                }
            }
            if (!pre.Equals("")) {
                Console.WriteLine(pre);
            }
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                Console.WriteLine("kosong");
            }
            else {
                for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine(s.get(i) + (i==s.size()-1 ? "\n" : " "));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s.size());
        }
```

i have dificultly to find some function java like search(), get(), and size() in c# ...any solution

My question is how to find equal java function like search(), get(), and size() in c#??

Comment: [C# - Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For `size` use `Count` property, for `get` call `ToArray` method then use indexer: `s.ToArray()[1]`, for search you can use LINQ, e.g.: `s.FirstOrDefault(x => x == ...)`

Comment: Was about to answer but i will say that i have diferent than you... You can also use s.ElementAt(i) in step of get(i)